# Lombok Annotation Processor with Gradle 4.9

Tags: lombok, annotation-processing, java-10, intellij-lombok-plugin, annotation-processor

If you get that exception/warning below, when you're using Gradle 4.9, downgrade to Gradle 4.8.

warning: lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor could not be initialized. Lombok will not run during this compilation: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.processing.IncrementalFiler cannot be cast to jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler

lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, Keep Java Version 10 & Downgrade to Gradle 4.8.